# Hidden iframe onload event

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I've seen some similar issues on here regarding the iframe `onload`, but nothing is working for me.

I have a hidden iframe that I use only for users to download a PDF that is dynamically created on my server.  When the user clicks a button, the PDF is created on my server by pointing to a controller/action along with a query string of parameters.

This works great.  However, I show a spinner and disable the UI when they press this button (`BlockAndSpin` function).  I want to turn the hide the spinner and re-enable the UI when the PDF has been downloaded.

My `onload` method is never hit when I debug in Chrome and Firefox.  I also tried to add the `onload` attribute to the iframe itself, and that didn't work either.  The file downloads, but the UI stays the same and the `onload` event doesn't fire.

js

```
function downloadPOS(id) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id)
    BlockAndSpin(true);
    ifrm.src = "/staticPOS/AddOrDownload" + GetPosQueryString();
    ifrm.onload = function () {
        BlockAndSpin(false);
    }
}
```

html

```
<iframe id="dlFrame" onload="BlockAndSpin(false);" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

Apparently this can't be done.  My response is a .pdf being downloaded by the user and not loading anything into the iframe itself, thusly it never fires the event.  I'll have to revisit how this is done.

Comment: just a suggestion - if the AddOrDownload is a page - or can be wrapped by a page, your onload method would be placed there.

Comment: a quick [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/t28Nv/) shows otherwise - the `iframe` *does* call the `onload` handler attached by its `onload` attribute. recheck your code for other issues.

Comment: 1) It isn't a page, it is a pdf that is returned.
2) If I comment out the actual download src, it works - but it must be related to something else regarding the download.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue attaching to messages on a hidden iframe. IE does not seem to like cross domain communication with "hidden" (display:none) iframes.

My workaround was to set the iframe to an absolute position with a left value of -9999px.  Then it's effectively hidden and you can attach to it.